# Arquillian with Payara Micro connector 1.1: NullPointer

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit, jboss-arquillian, payara-micro

I can't get this simple test to work with Arquillian and Payara.

I have the templates from the pyara blog ([Blogpost](https://blog.payara.fish/how-to-test-applications-with-payara-server-micro-with-arquillian)) and I have no idea what the problem is.

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.example.arquillian</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillianTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <payara.version>5.192</payara.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
                <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>fish.payara.arquillian</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-payara-micro-managed</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Download and copy Payara Micro artefact -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>fish.payara.extras</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>payara-micro</artifactId>
                                    <version>${payara.version}</version>
                                    <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Configure Payara Micro Runtime -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <environmentVariables>
                        <MICRO_JAR>${project.basedir}/target/payara-micro-${payara.version}.jar</MICRO_JAR>
                    </environmentVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

HelloWorld.java

```
public class HelloWorld {

    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

HelloWorldTest

```
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;


@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class HelloWorldTest {


    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
                .addClass(HelloWorld.class);
    }


    @Test()
    public void sayHelloTest() {
        HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
        Assert.assertEquals(helloWorld.sayHello(), "Hello World");
    }
}
```

The HelloworldTest should pass, but i get 
HelloWorldTest.HelloWorldTest » NullPointer

I don't know how to further simplify it and think there is a configuration error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: No the error is not thrown by my "code" but by Arquillian.
There is some missconfiguration between Payara Micro and Arquillian, or a bug somewhere.

Comment: can you add the actual Java stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is caused by the payara arquillian connector.
Version 1.1 and 1.2-Snapshot have this bug.

You shoud use 1.0Beta3 as rieckpil in his answer show.

I have rasied a Issue on Github and this bug is confirmed. (PAYARA-3991)
[Gihub Issue](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/4080).

So hopefully this will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the following dependency:

```
 <dependency>
   <groupId>fish.payara.arquillian</groupId>
   <artifactId>arquillian-payara-micro-managed</artifactId>
   <version>1.1</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

with

```
<groupId>fish.payara.arquillian</groupId>
     <artifactId>arquillian-payara-micro-5-managed</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.Beta3</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

As described in the [blog](https://blog.payara.fish/how-to-test-applications-with-payara-server-micro-with-arquillian) post you are referring to.

I have a running example for Payara Micro 5.192 and JUnit 4.12 and Arquillian on [GitHub](https://github.com/rieckpil/learning-samples/tree/master/arquillian-payara-micro-example). You can check out the repository and just run `mvn test` in the `arquillian-payara-micro-example` folder and everything should work.

Comment: This is true, with 1.0Beta3 it works, but 1.1 or 1.2-snapshot throws this error.

Thank you for your help. I mark your  answer  as solution, until the bug is fixed